# Sharepoint API - How to Upload files to Sharepoint Doc Library from ASP.NET Web Application

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I am new to Sharepoint Server, Do we have any utility to upload files from ASP.NET application.

Could you please provide your valuable answers?

Answer (score 7):

You can write some custom code to do it. You could use the SharePoint API if you are on the same server or use WebServices

Here is the sample code assuming that you know the url of the document library and you are uploading the document to the root folder. You will have to add Microsoft.SharePoint.dll as reference to your ASP.NET project

```
        using (SPSite siteCollection = new SPSite(url))
        {
            using (SPWeb spWeb = siteCollection.OpenWeb())
            {
                SPList spList = spWeb.GetList(url);

                string fileName = "XXXX";
                FileStream fileStream = null;
                Byte[] fileContent = null;

                try
                {
                    string docPath = XXXX; //physical location of the file
                    fileStream = File.OpenRead(docPath + fileName);
                    fileContent = new byte[Convert.ToInt32(fileStream.Length)];
                    fileStream.Read(fileContent, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fileStream.Length));

                    spList.RootFolder.Files.Add(spList.RootFolder.Url + "/" + fileName, fileContent, true);
                    spList.Update();
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {

                }
                finally
                {
                    if (fileStream != null)
                    {
                        fileStream.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: You can also use SPFolder.Add(url, Stream, overwrite) instead of reading the whole file into memory (which can lead to performance issues if you plan to upload large files)